# concept behind words occuring close by in topic modeling

Tags: r, data-visualization, topic-models

So I have been reading a lot on topic modeling and word clouds. I understood the working of LDA via Gibbs sampling. What I didn't understood is when we plot the results of topic modeling via wordcloud, what is the concept behind two words occuring close by..as n what is the algo behind it because we know that distance between 2 words signifies the likelihood of observeing a word given that the other has occured,i.e., closer the words, higher is the likelihood of seeing them together. 
In the R-code for wordcloud, it says words are displayed in decresing order frequency, which is doubtful as size of the word depends on frequency so the output is never in form of a series. I want to know how does it work...like autocorrelation between words is calculated or there is any other concept....

Comment: I believe the "..displayed in decreasing order frequency.." has to do with the algorithm that finds specific places for words in the wordcloud. So it starts with the most frequent and largest word, places it. Then it picks the next one and finds a suitable place for it and so on.

Comment: and how does it finds that suitable place..what is the logic?